# Xtensor operator<<overload

Tags: c++, xtensor

I want to keep variant inside xtensor, but when I try to print the tensor the overload for operator<< is not picked up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xtensor/xarray.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xio.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xview.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xadapt.hpp>
#include <variant>

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const std::variant<T, Ts...>& v) {
    std::visit([&os](auto &&arg) {
        os << arg;
    }, v);
    return os;
}

void foo() {
    xt::xtensor<std::variant<double, std::string>, 2>::shape_type shape = {1,1};
    xt::xtensor<std::variant<double, std::string>, 2> ret(shape);

    std::variant<double, std::string> a = 2.5;

    ret.at(0, 0) =a;

    std::cout << a << std::endl; //works
    std::cout << ret << std::endl; //doesn`t work
}
```

Comment: The [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) will look for `ret` `operator<<` to be in `std` and `xt`.  The `xt` implementation will only be aware of the global namespace `operator<<` for `std::variant` that is declared or is forward declared **before** that `xt` `operator<<` (which I presume is a template).

Comment: Why does std::cout << a << std::endl; work? Both arguments are form std and still we pick up function from global namespace.

Comment: The `a` appears *after* the `operator<<` is declared.  If you move your `operator<<` declaration *after* the `main` scope, then the `std::cout << a << std::endl;` will fail.

Comment: ret appers after  ```operator<<``` as well. Even if I move the declaration before the xtensor headers it still doesn`t work.

Comment: Neither ADL *nor* ordinary lookup will find your `operator<<` in the global namespace. I'm not familiar with `xtensor`, but I assume there's something like this in namespace `xt`: `operator<<(ostream& os, xtensor<T>& x) { os << x.getT(); }`. Therefore, the lookup for `operator<<` will occur from inside namespace `xt`. It will search for all `operator<<` overloads in namespace `xt`, and only if none are found, will look up in the enclosing namespace. But obviously, there do exists `operator<<` overloads in `xt`; so the lookup won't reach the global namespace.

Comment: This is how ordinary lookup works: it searches inside out for a declaration of a given name, and stops as soon as any such declarations are found - even if overload resolution later finds them all non-viable, or access control finds them inaccessible.

Comment: The `operator<<` for `ret` appears in the header files, in the `xt` namespace, **before** the `operator<<` provided here in this file.